# wix - heat.exe generate an id of directory

Tags: wix, heat

by heat was generated code like
`<DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">

            <Directory Id="dir77AA1A0808D9092357CFE6C2BECDEE70" Name="files" />`
please, tell what is this strange Id of directory. i want to copy dll in applicationfolder. should i change this id to something like INSTALLDIR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like a GUID, ie a unique identifier for a directory referenced elsewhere in your wix project.

You can change it, but if you do make sure you change all references to that identifier.

Comment: i understand this, gbjbaanb. i just want to clarify. installer will create new folder on targetdir named "files" and dll will be installed in this folder,will they?thank you for reply